# Why convert a folder to an application in IIS?

Tags: iis, web-applications

When creating a site you have the option on the sub folders with in to convert them to an application. Why and when would you ever need to do this and what are the advantages and disadvantages? And what is the difference now that it is an application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why and when would you ever need to use an application

When you want to make your websites more robust.

> What are the advantages of an application?

You can isolate a website when it's an application - the site has its own Session state and Application state, it is in effect a new standalone application. When the website has a problem it won't impact other websites on the server. The following description might help:

> An application belongs to an application pool, which isolates the
>   application from applications in other application pools on the
>   server.

[This link](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis) is really helpful and discusses applications and virtual directories in IIS.